# Invalid color for green pixels

Tags: java, image, colors

For a simulation i need to parse an image. The problem is, that the code below returns a wrong value for the green color.

```html
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(string));
Simulation s = new Simulation(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
int index = -1;
for(int y = 0; y<img.getHeight(); y++){
 for(int x = 0; x<img.getWidth(); x++){
  index++;
  if(pixels[index*4+1]==0&&pixels[index*4+2]==0&&pixels[index*4+3]==0)continue;
  int r = pixels[index*4+1]; //<-- correct value (in the tested case)
  int g = pixels[index*4+2]; //<-- wrong value
  int b = pixels[index*4+3]; //<-- correct value (in the tested case)
  if(r<0)r=Math.abs(r)+128;
  if(g<0){
   System.out.println(g);
   g=Math.abs(g)+128;
  }
  if(b<0)b=Math.abs(b)+128;
  Color c = getColor(r, g, b);
  int rgb = c.getRed() * 256 * 256 + c.getGreen() * 256 + c.getBlue();
  if(rgb!=0)System.out.println("FC: "+rgb+ " "+ c.getRed() + " " + c.getGreen() + " " + c.getBlue());
    }
}
```

The problem with this is, that when the color value is above 127, the numbers get negative. Thats why I built the check `if(g<0)`.

The color tested is Red: 76 Green: 177 Blue: 34.
The value in code is 76 -79 34 before the check, and 76 207 34 afterwards (resulting in +30 green). Why doesn't the green pixel array index return the expected -49 (177 unsigned = -49 signed)?

Thank you! :)

Comment: I ain't sure what are you trying to do but this line `int rgb = c.getRed() * 256 * 256 + c.getGreen() * 256 + c.getBlue();` shouldn't it be `int rgb = c.getRed() * 256 + c.getGreen() * 256 + c.getBlue() * 256;`

Comment: That line is simply for converting the red, green and blue byte to an rgb integer.

Comment: There is no problem with that line^^

Comment: Are you sure about the indexes? (index*4+1, index*4+2, index*4+3?). And 7617734 is 0x743CC6=(116, 60, 198)

Comment: yeah, the indexes seem to be correct. I meant Red: 76, Green: 177 and Blue: 34 ;) I will edit that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why only green has a bad value is because it's the only one > 128.
`if(r<0)r=Math.abs(r)+128;` this is wrong -> for example -1 shoud be 255. Your formula gives 127.
Use this formula: `if(r<0)r=r+256;` and -79 will be 177
Same thing for green and blue.

Why not use `Byte.toUnsignedInt`

Comment: Oh, i didn't know about that method. Thank you :)